# C# Reflection with Picture Box

Tags: c#, oop, reflection, picturebox

I want to do the following:

```
          string WhoIsTheSender="pictureBox1";

        switch (WhoIsTheSender)
        {
           case "pictureBox1":  
                    pictureBox1.Image = Properties.Resources.ledOff; 
                    break;
           case "pictureBox2":  
                    pictureBox2.Image = Properties.Resources.ledOff;
                    break;
            //....until case "pictureBox64":  pictureBox64.Image = Properties.Resources.ledOff;
                    break;
        }
```

Is there a possible way to make it much shorter? How do I use reflection?

```
string WhoIsTheSender="pictureBox1";
        WhoIsTheSender.Image = Properties.Resources.ledOff; //in this specific example WhoIsTheSender="pictureBox1";
```

Thank for the help in advance!

Comment: Yes it is an event, basically I have 64 picture boxes which go to the same event. I don't want to handle all the events separately, so I have 1 event only. Once I click on a specific box, I get the name of the picture box. Let's say I clicked on  a picture box called "pictureBox1". I get the string itself, but now I want to use this string to modify that picture boxes image.

Comment: `((Control)sender).Name` should give you the name of the picturebox that is raising the event. You could also just do `((Picturebox)sender).Image = Properties.Resources.ledOff;`, I don't see the need for reflection here. The `sender` property is a reference to the control raising the event...

Comment: Sorry, I didn't post the whole code, just the simplified version. Yes, I did get name of the button using the line:  string WhoIsTheSender = ((PictureBox)sender).Name;

Comment: Is there no way for me to use the name of the picture box as a modifier other than using a dictionary? For example:                                                                                                  string WhoIsTheSender="pictureBox1";
WhoIsTheSender.Image = Properties.Resources.ledOff;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Yes it is an event, basically I have 64 picture boxes which go to the same event. I don't want to handle all the events separately, so I have 1 event only.

The information you need is already available in the event's `sender` parameter.

If you're sure the `sender` is always a `PictureBox`, then one line (of non-reflection) will do:

```
(PictureBox(sender)).Image = Properties.Resources.ledOff;
```

If you're *not* sure of the `sender` type, then test it first:

```
var picBox = sender as PictureBox;

if (picBox != null)
    picBox.Image = Properties.Resources.ledOff;
```

Comment: Wow! Thank you so much! That did the trick! I was stuck for 4 hours. I understand it now. Sender object is of type object, cast it to PictureBox type and then access its .Image property. What i was doing was trying to access a string's image property(which doesn't make sense). Thank you once again!

Comment: @RudolfBardos, you should mark this as the answer if it satisfied your needs.